# Gnuplot smooth isolines in splot with hidden3d

Tags: gnuplot

This could be a bug in gnuplot, I am not sure...
It seems that with `hidden3d` activated in `splot`, the `samples` match the `isosamples`, i.e. the **isolines become jagged**.

I am trying to create the following plot, but with hidden3d activated.
[image: Smooth isolines on a sphere]
This is currently the result:
[image: Sphere isolines with hidden3d]

**The Question**:

is there any way to get the isolines smooth again?

---

**The Script**:

```
set key at screen 1, 0.9, 0 right top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitle nobox
set style textbox opaque margins  0.5,  0.5 noborder

set view 60, 30, 1, 1.1

set samples 200, 200
set isosamples 51, 51

#set contour surface

set cntrlabel  format '%8.3g' font ',7' start 5 interval 20
set cntrparam levels auto 10
set style data lines

set title "contour on sphere" 

set xlabel "X axis" 
set ylabel "Y axis" 
set zlabel "Z " 
set zlabel  offset character 1, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate

set parametric
set samples 1000, 1000
set isosamples 21, 11

set mapping spherical
set angles radians
r=1

set hidden3d
splot [-pi:pi][-pi/2:pi/2] r*cos(v)*cos(u),r*cos(v)*sin(u),r*sin(v) with lines lw 1.5 lt 1 lc rgb '#777777'
```

Comment: I think that this is a "feature", from help on "hidden3d": "Functions are evaluated at isoline intersections. The algorithm interpolates
 linearly between function points or data points when determining the visible
 line segments. This means that the appearance of a function may be different when plotted with hidden3d than when plotted with nohidden3d because in the latter case functions are evaluated at each sample."

Comment: I see. Then the question is if there is an easier way than to manually calculate the circles.
Probably the easiest solution would be simply two for-loops?